# How to add pattern to bash completion (for unzip)?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When I type

```
unzip <tab>
```

I get a list of all files ending in `.zip`, which is the standard behavior of tab completion for the `unzip` command.

However, I also want bash completion for `unzip` list files which end in `.udp`, in addition to `.zip` files. How can I achieve this behavior in my local `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 25):

*Instead of keeping on commenting …*

---

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(zip|udp)' unzip
```

should add completion for

```
-f -X '!*.@(zip|udp)'
 |  |  | |||________|
 |  |  | ||     |
 |  |  | ||     +- filterpat: zip or udp
 |  |  | |+-------------  @ : Matches one of the given patterns
 |  |  | +-------------- *. : Anything+<dot>
 |  |  +----------------  ! : Negate
 |  +------------------- -X : Filter out matches in "filterpat"
 +---------------------- -f : files
```

In other words: *Complete files and remove all not ending in `.zip` or `.udp`.*

---

### Extras

If you add `-o default` completion will complete/match ***all*** files and directories if there is ***no*** files ending in `.zip` or `.udp`.

If you add `-o plusdirs` completion will add any directories ***in addition*** to any matches of files ending in `.zip` or `.udp`.

### Current

When you use `complete -p unzip` you get current pattern.

From your comments it sounds mostly like you are missing either `+` or `@` in pattern, as in:

```
# Err:
complete -f -X '!*.(zip|udp)' unzip
                   |
                   +---- Missing + or @
```

which would mean *match any file literally ending in `.(zip|udp)`*. E.g.

```
touch 'file_test.(zip|udp)'
```

Also have a look at this section of the manual:

- [3.5.8 Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)
- [4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

it is possible e.g. `extglob` is not enabled. Enable by:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Check current status of all `shopt` settings by entering:

```
shopt
```

---

### Function

If that is `-F something` it means it uses a function named *something* to generate the list of completions.

The `_filedir_xspec` is typically a Debian function. You might have something like this:

```
$ cat /etc/bash_completion
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

Which means `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` get sourced. Here you'll find the [function in question](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob;f=bash_completion;h=c684a8fd9ded8b79b3ecbbbe30728679dbded276;hb=e777395ac3ce25527e58e04bfc406ae03bdb3b12#l1821). A few lines further down you see that this function / completion is added by a function named [`_install_xspec`](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob;f=bash_completion;h=c684a8fd9ded8b79b3ecbbbe30728679dbded276;hb=e777395ac3ce25527e58e04bfc406ae03bdb3b12#l1863) by e.g.:

```
_install_xspec '!*.@(zip|[ejsw]ar|exe|pk3|wsz|zargo|xpi|s[tx][cdiw]|sx[gm]|o[dt][tspgfc]|od[bm]|oxt|epub|apk|do[ct][xm]|p[op]t[mx]|xl[st][xm])' unzip zipinfo
```

---

### Manual entries:

- [8.7 Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html)
- [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

---

### Update to comments 1:

*– No match due to invalid archives or file permissions.*

This should not affect the result. `complete` only matches files given by the rules and do no processing of the files. If you can list them with `ls`, they should match.

As a side note one *could* add such a functionality by using a complete function:

```
function _unzip_validated() {
    # 1. Generate list of files ending in e.g. .zip and .udp
    # 2. Validate each file and remove invalid ones from file list.
}

complete -F _unzip_validated unzip
```

---

*– Colors. Why does `ls` distinguish `test.zip` from `test.upd`?*

This does not affect `complete`. Colors by `ls` are provided by [`$LS_COLORS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html). Try:

```
echo "$LS_COLORS" | tr : '\n' | sort
```

You should see something like `*.zip=01;31` which means:

```
*.zip=01;31
|____| |  |
   |   |  +--- Red
   |   +------ Bold
   +---------- Files with .zip extension
```

`*.udp` on the other hand has no entry associated with it, so no coloring.

---

### Next step (should have been first)

1. Open terminal and go to a directory with test files. Both .zip and .udp
2. Enter `bash --norc`
3. Enter `complete -f -X '!*.@(zip|udp)' unzip`
4. Enter `shopt -s extglob`
5. Enter `unzip <tab><tab>`

Result?

Also, click [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/108423/edit) below your question and add output of:

```
bind -V
shopt
env
```

might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent and lengthy explanation, but still it does not work. `complete -p unzip` yields `complete -f -X '!*.@(zip|udp)' unzip`, and `unzip <tab>` completes the file named `test.zip`. However, the directory contains a file named `test.upd` as well which is not found by tab completion of `unzip`. Do the fact of file permissions or a zero length of the file maybe explain this weird behavior?

Comment: @Alex: Should get completion on both empty and valid files, as well as on files where one do not have permission. Is it the same behavior if you add it to a test script? E.g. 1. some test script with execution set: `~/bin/testing`, 2. `complete -f -X '!*.@(zip|udp)' testing`, 3. `testing <tab><tab>` ?

Comment: @Alex: You could also update Q with output of `shopt` …

Comment: `extglob` is activated. The example with 'testing' selects the `zip` file only again. I notice that `test.zip` is shown in red color, while `test.upd` is shown in white color with `ls -l`, both files empty with same permissions, ownershift and group association. Why does `ls` distinguish `test.zip` from `test.upd`? Maybe this is a hint towards the problem I have?

Comment: @Alex: Added an update.

Answer (score 3):

In the file `/etc/bash_completion`, which you are presumably sourcing somewhere, the default completion, at least for my version of `bash` (v4.2.25) is

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(zip|[ejw]ar|exe|pk3|wsz|zargo|xpi|sxw|o[tx]t|od[fgpst]|epub|apk)' unzip zipinfo
```

Try changing the entire expression to

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(zip|[ejw]ar|exe|pk3|wsz|zargo|xpi|sxw|o[tx]t|od[fgpst]|epub|apk|udp)' unzip zipinfo
```

And add to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: This does not solve my problem. If I do so and source it, `unzip <tab>` neither finds `.zip` nor `.upd` files nor other files.

Comment: Try hitting **tab** twice, see if that's any different. 
Do other completions work as expected? For example `gzip` with `.gz` files?

Comment: Hitting tab twice does not change anything. Using `gunzip` with `.gz` files select only files ending in `.gz`, but the definition is also different: `complete -F _filedir_xspec gunzip`.

Comment: Do you source the file `/etc/bash_completion` in your `.bashrc` ?

Comment: Try `shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line in your .bashrc:

```
complete -f -o default -X '!*.+(zip|udp)' unzip
```

Comment: It seems with this suggestion I will find `.udp` files, but only if no `.zip` files are present. If a `test.zip` and `test.udp` file is present in the current directory, `unzip <tab>` only lists the `.zip` file. I would expect to see both files (i.e. the bash completion would give `test.`).

Comment: Are you sure? I checked on my bash and I seem to find both `udp` and `zip` files. Did you source `.bashrc` after adding the line?

Comment: I repeated in a new terminal, and now `unzip <tab>` list all files, even ones ending in a different phrase. Now quite what I need.

Comment: Strange.. I am running GNU bash version 4.2.25 and works as expected. Which version of bash are you on?

Comment: Could you try adding two separate lines: `complete -f -o default -X '!*.zip' unzip` and `complete -f -o default -X '!*.udp' unzip`

Comment: I am using also GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1). With those lines, `unzip` will either find ONLY a `.upd` file or ONLY the `.zip` file (when the `complete ... upd` line is commented out).

Comment: @Alex: enter `complete -p unzip` to view rule that is in effect. You would also probably want to add `-o plusdirs` instead of `-o default`

Comment: The rule is as defined, and with `-o plusdirs` instead of `-o default` bash completion does not complete anything.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `_filedir` instead of "raw" `complete`.

**Justification**

- `grep _filedir -r $(pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion) | wc -l`
- tilde (`~`) paths are being expanded
- Prefixes are removed for directories, i.e. for `/home/tux/Do<TAB><TAB>`, the list you get as a reply removes '/home/tux' and is thus much more compact
- Easier to implement and more failsafe

**MWE**

```
_unzip_completor()
{
    # init bash-completion's stuff
    _init_completion || return

    # fill COMPREPLY using bash-completion's routine
    _filedir '@(zip|udp)'
}
complete -F _unzip_completor unzip
```