# How to properly use "complete -G"?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've generated the simplest code I could think of to illustrate my problem.

Suppose I want the "foo" command to work with files that end with ".cc".

```
complete -G '*.cc' foo
```

Now let's suppose my current directory contains "foo.cc", "bar.cc", and "blah.cc". If I type "foo" and tab, I get:

```
$ foo <tab><tab>
bar.cc   blah.cc  foo.cc   
$ foo
```

which I expected. But if I type the first letter 'b' and try again:

```
$ foo b<tab><tab>
bar.cc   blah.cc  foo.cc
$ foo b
```

It didn't filter the results to those that start with 'b' as it would have for -W.

I've searched everything I could find, and haven't found an example of `complete -G` that does what I want. I'm sure this is a common-enough thing to do; what's the best practices here?

Comment: I should add: I'm actually using `compgen -G` from within a function called with `complete -F`, so solutions involving scripts are perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the answer in [How to add pattern to bash completion (for unzip)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108423/)

Executive summary: "-G" is pretty much useless. The best way to do it is to use "-f" which matches all files, and then -X '!*.cc' to exclude the ones I don't want. And then "add -o plusdirs" for good measure.